# Xcode merge conflict - how to select "all right" for all the conflicts?

Tags: xcode

while merging 2 branches I encountered 1452 conflicts in the project.pbxproj file.

I want to "choose right" for all these conflicts, is there a way to do that once for all or I have to manually select choose right for 1452 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout --theirs .` in the command line (Terminal app)

either this or `git checkout --ours .` depending if you want what you had on the branch (`ours`) or what you just pulled (`theirs`)

I don't believe Xcode has that

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the following:

download Kintsugi (https://github.com/Lightricks/Kintsugi)

```
gem install kintsugi
kintsugi install-driver
```

This will resolve 98% of conflicts automatically in your project files!